Corn snake death
Okay my corn snake died this morning and i don’t know why. He was four, he had a heating pad under his cave, along with me changing the water every day or every other day depending on weather and his cage condition and feeding him every 1-2 week (he would act a certain why when he wanted food so i would go off that). If you aren’t aware he was his breeding season where he’ll refuse to eat so usually from mid april to june i won’t feed him, i heard snakes can store fat for 6 months so this was fine. I woke up and he was dead, and i have no clue why.

Does this answer your question? My snake died suddenly
